# PHP Outputs Multiple HTML Tables

Tags: php, html, html-table, echo

I'm fairly new to PHP and was wondering how I could output this information into one table.

```
<?php

$url='mysite.com';
$content = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($content->children() as $alarm) {

$severity = $alarm['severity'];
$id = $alarm ['id'];


echo "<table boarder=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Header1</th><th>ID</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th><th>Header4</th>      <th>Header5</th></tr>";

echo "<td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
echo $severity;
echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
echo $id;

echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
echo $alarm->nodeId;
echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
echo $alarm->nodeLabel;

echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";

echo $alarm->lastEventTime;
echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=500px >";
echo  $alarm->logMessage;
echo "</td>";
echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

This is the output...

```
Header1     Header2      Header3            Header4                Header5**
$severity     $id       $alarm->nodeID    $alarm->$nodeLabel    $$alarm->logmessage

Header1     Header2      Header3            Header4                Header5
$severity     $id       $alarm->nodeID    $alarm->$nodeLabel    $$alarm->logmessage

Header1     Header2      Header3            Header4                Header5
$severity     $id       $alarm->nodeID    $alarm->$nodeLabel    $$alarm->logmessage
```

The html output is as follows...

```
<table boarder="1">...</table>
<table boarder="1">...</table>
<table boarder="1">...</table>
<table boarder="1">...</table>
```

I just want it so it is in one table with the headers only on the top.

```
Header1     Header2      Header3            Header4                Header5**
$severity[0]     $id       $alarm->nodeID    $alarm->$nodeLabel    $$alarm->logmessage
$severity[1]     $id       $alarm->nodeID    $alarm->$nodeLabel    $$alarm->logmessage
$severity[2]     $id       $alarm->nodeID    $alarm->$nodeLabel    $$alarm->logmessage
```

Any suggestions on how to get this information all into one table or best practices would be great.

Comment: Who downvoted this question? It had sufficient information, and shows an attempt at coding (just poor understanding of what it was doing).

Comment: Always understand, that if you place `table` inside the `for loop` the number of elements present would be the number of table's formed coz of iteration. Hence you should print table tag & its table head i.e. first `tr` tag before for loop starts and close the `table` tag after for loop end, and within the `for` loop you should only keep that code which is meant to iterate and print each row

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification on this. I knew I was close but skipped right passed where to place my headers. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print the `<table boarder=1>` and the headers before the `foreach` loop and then print out the closing table tag after your finished. Also encapsulate the `$content->children()` in a table row tag for good measure.

```
<?php

echo "<table boarder=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Header1</th><th>ID</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th><th>Header4</th>      <th>Header5</th></tr>";

foreach ($content->children() as $alarm) {
    $severity = $alarm['severity'];
    $id = $alarm ['id'];

    echo "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
    echo $severity;
    echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
    echo $id;

    echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
    echo $alarm->nodeId;
    echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";
    echo $alarm->nodeLabel;

    echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >";

    echo $alarm->lastEventTime;
    echo "</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=500px >";
    echo  $alarm->logMessage;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Good to see you picked up on his missing <tr>

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the fast response.

Comment: User, please remember to hit the check mark next to the answer that you used. Always do that so that person can get credit

Comment: Thanks Brad! I was trying to vote on it but don't have enough points. Just updated. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your

```
echo "<table boarder=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Header1</th><th>ID</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th><th>Header4</th>      <th>Header5</th></tr>";
```

before your `foreach()` condition, not inside

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo "<table boarder=1>";
    echo "<tr><th>Header1</th><th>ID</th><th>Header2</th><th>Header3</th><th>Header4</th>      <th>Header5</th></tr>";

    foreach ($content->children() as $alarm) {

        echo "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >".$alarm->severity."</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >".$alarm->id."</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >".$alarm->nodeId."</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >".$alarm->nodeLabel."</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=100px >".$alarm->lastEventTime."</td><td style=\"text-align:center\" width=500px >".$alarm->logMessage."</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```